# How to get pointer to an actual cardano address by pool script hash in format "script...."?

Tags: cardano-db-sync, utxo, script

The address format is **script15ew2tzjwn364l2pszu7j5h9w63v2crrnl97m074w9elrkxhah0e**. In this example from https://github.com/DefiLlama/DefiLlama-Adapters/blob/main/projects/minswap/index.js, you can observe that by using the address in the format **script...** with the getAdaInAddress function, Koios will return it.

However, achieving the same result with Cardano-db-sync is a bit more challenging. I couldn't find any reference to the **script...** format in the database.

I also attempted to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/cardano-addresses, but this format triggered an error with the inspectAddress function.